# Ubuntu delete group by GID

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ansible

I have recently used ansible's dynamic inventory capabilities to manage some ec2s. In the process of developing a script that creates and verifies groups on my dynamic inventory I have created approximately 80 groups. As consequence of the bad script, these groups are named after security groups, ids, vpcs, tag names, and such. I would like to delete these groups.

I recognize using the GIDs is the best way to delete. However both the `userdel` and `deluser` commands do not provide options to specify the GID. This leads me to tediously name all groups on my dynamic inventory for deletion.

I am able to `sudo cat /etc/group` and with some `grep` can almost get a list of the names but I find it easier to just specify a range of GIDs for the extraneous groups.

I am looking for some shell commands or ansible module that I can add to a playbook. Any code or script provided is highly valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the gids, each convert to group name and call `groupdel` on each of the group name:

```
 # print gid numbers separated by newlines
 printf "%s\n" 2000 2001 2002 $other_gid_number |
 # convert gid numbers to group names
 xargs -I{} awk -F: '$3 == {}' /etc/group | cut -d: -f1 |
 # to delete groups remove the echo
 xargs -n1 echo userdel
```

or a oneliner:

```
printf "%s\n" 2000 2001 2002 $other_gid_number | xargs -I{} awk -F: '$3 == {}' /etc/group | cut -d: -f1 | xargs -n1 echo userdel
```

> sudo cat /etc/group

You don't need sudo to access `/etc/group`. It should be readable by everyone.

Comment: This seems to work for explicit GIDs but I have a range. I'm roughly working with 1007-1084.

Comment: `seq 1007 1084`. `for i in {1007..1084}; do printf "%s\n" "$i"; done` Please pay attention to `;`, `"` and `$`. Also just `printf "%s\n" {1007..1084}`.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. Note that I'm using groupdel.

Comment: Would you also be able to diagnose why I have this error `groupdel: Permission denied.
groupdel: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
`

Comment: probably you have to run groupdel as root. Add sudo in front of it. `xargs -n1 sudo groupdel`